# How/where to store secrets for a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension. However, I don't really know how/where to keep my API keys and other sensitive information that'll be used by my extension. In the end, I'll have to submit this extension for review to Google.

Comment: Sensitive information shouldn't be in client-side code. If you're calling an API that requires secret credentials, the extension should go through your server, and the secrets belong there.

Comment: What about when I want to report errors from within my extension for example? In my case I've got a Sentry DSN and I don't think I should directly include this in code.

Comment: It depends on how serious it is if someone can impersonate you. Is it a problem if someone can spoof error messages to your Sentry?

Comment: Well, probably it's not that harmful, at this stage I wouldn't even care anyway, but I just wanted to ask anyway as it seems like it wasn't mentioned anywhere before or at least I couldn't find anything about it. Maybe it was obvious to everyone except me. :P

Comment: I'll give an example. Credit card processing services have two APIs, each with different API keys. There's an API for turning the card number into an opaque token, it has a "public" API key. There's an API for charging the card, it has a private API key. The first is used from the client, the second is only used from the server, so no one else can spoof your key to make charges.

Answer (score 1):

Consider your chrome extension the same as a webpage. Any gated (authenticated) communication to an API you should proxy through a server. Do not have any credentials client side in your webpage code.